# "outerHtml of undefined" Error in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have these string

```
var str = '<div class="page">&lt;div class</div>
<div class="page">=&quot;nodejs-c</div>
<div class="page">lass&quot;&gt;Wakh</div>
<div class="page">ed un sing</div>
<div class="page">e sur son </div>
<div class="page">argent les</div>
<div class="page"> appelle d</div>
<div class="page">e l&#39;argent</div>
<div class="page"> et garçon</div>
<div class="page">asseoir S</div>
<div class="page">inge incha</div>
<div class="page">ngée.&lt;&#x2F;div</div>
<div class="page">&gt;</div>';
```

I try to wrap the page class with pageWrap

```
var content = $(str).wrap('<div id="source-wrapper"></div>')
                    .find('.page')
                    .wrap('<div class="pageWrap"></div>')
                    .closest('.pageWrap')
                    .text(function() {
                        return $(this).html()
                    })
                    .closest('#source-wrapper')
                    [0].outerHTML;
```

I got outHtml of undefined? Is there anything wrong in my text() function?

Comment: What you are trying to achieve?

Comment: I dont think your string is correct: `&lt;div class</div>` will be `<div class </div>`. Is that what you want?

Answer (score 0):

You had already selected `.page` so [`find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find) method won't work here which search `.page` within it but there are no elements with that class within it. Finally, you are trying to get dom object which id undefined and nothing get selected and returns `undefined` and you are trying to get `outerHTML` property from `undefined`.

Use [`wrappAll()`](http://api.jquery.com/wrapall/) method to wrap all the elements using a single element and then there is no need of [`find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find) method since it's already collection of `.page` element.

```js
var str = '<div class="page">&lt;div class</div><div class="page">=&quot;nodejs-c</div><div class="page">lass&quot;&gt;Wakh</div><div class="page">ed un sing</div><div class="page">e sur son </div><div class="page">argent les</div><div class="page"> appelle d</div><div class="page">e l&#39;argent</div><div class="page"> et garçon</div><div class="page"> asseoir S</div><div class="page">inge incha</div><div class="page">ngée.&lt;&#x2F;div</div><div class="page">&gt;</div>';


var content = $(str)
  // wrap all the elements by a single tag
  .wrapAll('<div id="source-wrapper"></div>')
  // wrap each individual element
  .wrap('<div class="pageWrap"></div>')
  .closest('.pageWrap')
  .text(function() {
    return $(this).html();
  })
  .closest('#source-wrapper')[0].outerHTML;

console.log(content);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: when I append content, is it possible to convert `&lt;div ` to normal html like `<div` ?

Comment: @NatelyJamerson : you need to do the reverse for that :) `.html(function(){  return $(this).text(); })` - but this may make it invalid some times... :)

Answer (score -1):

Just remove `[0]` part as `#source-wrapper` will return only one element and not array of elements.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var content = $('.page').wrap('<div id="source-wrapper"></div>').find('.page')
    .wrap('<div class="pageWrap"></div>')
    .closest('.pageWrap')
    .text(function() {
      return $(this).html()
    })
    .closest('#source-wrapper')
    .outerHTML;
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="page">&lt;div class</div>
<div class="page">=&quot;nodejs-c</div>
<div class="page">lass&quot;&gt;Wakh</div>
<div class="page">ed un sing</div>
<div class="page">e sur son</div>
<div class="page">argent les</div>
<div class="page">appelle d</div>
<div class="page">e l&#39;argent</div>
<div class="page">et garçon</div>
<div class="page">asseoir S</div>
<div class="page">inge incha</div>
<div class="page">ngée.&lt;&#x2F;div</div>
<div class="page">&gt;</div>
```

Comment: `[0]` returns the DOM element in this scenario which has `outerHTML` property. `.closest('#source-wrapper')` returns jQuery object which doesn't have the property.